# Openshot Video Editor 1.4.3-1.2 - How to stop it auto updating to v 2.43 etc in 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-center, openshot

Basically, the latest version `openshot-qt` increases file size, which does not have any advantages. I have a lot of 2-hours length mp4 video, which were cut from 2-3 hours plus F1 downloads. The original files are in mkv or mp4 container with approximately 8-12GB size.

Using the old `openshot` 1.4.3-1.2, I was very happy with the small file size and quality at 720p 25fps using `xlib264` and `AAC` which outputs 1.4GB file. However, the latest version increases the file size to 3GB.

So I uninstalled `openshot-qt` and installed `openshot_1.4.3-1.2_all.deb`. It had missing dependencies, but worked perfectly. But Ubuntu 18.04 keeps uninstalling and installing the latest `openshot-qt`. I used *Synaptic Package Manager* to mark this as locked but, Ubuntu keeps updating openshot. All I want is to use the old *Openshot Video Editor* without self auto-updating to the latest version (which does not always work with audio and increases file size).

Is there any way to lock the version of old *Openshot Video Editor*?

Comment: Pinning / locking it in Synaptic should work. Please provide a screenshot of Synaptic showing the locked package. Also `apt policy XXX` where XXX is the package(s) you are trying to prevent being updated.  Update your question with this information, don't post it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clarification:

- Locking the version in *Synaptic Package Manager* does not mark it
  locked in other package managers (`dpkg`, `apt`, `aptitude`, ...)
- In Ubuntu, there is a package called `unattended-upgrades` that will
  automatically update your system to the latest version periodically.
- This means that your computer will install the latest version of `openshot` when available, because your lock works only inside the *Synaptic Package Manager*.
- Run `sudo apt upgrade`, if you see openshot among packages that will be updated, then

### What to do:

Do this:

```
echo "openshot hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

sudo apt-mark hold openshot
```

This will mark them **hold** in `dpkg` and `apt`.

### Remove Lock

```
echo "openshot install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-mark unhold openshot
```

This will remove lock in `dpkg` and `apt`.

Comment: Thanks, this has now stopped openshot from updating, how do I undo in the future if I want to update this software ?

Comment: @Martin, I updated the answer