# Install an old OpenShot release in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, versions, release-management, openshot

OpenShot is a free video editing software. In 2017, developpers updated it in a QT version. Recently I moved to Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 16.04 so I had no choice and had to use the new version of OpenShot. But, this version is paradoxaly slow and not precise at all. So can you help me to downgrade to the former version 1.4.3(for instance) instead of 2.x version(the new one) ?

I tested many alternative like Shotcut, Flowblade or Kdenlive but I prefere the old OpenShot. I know that what I ask for can create an unstable system but I really need it for school and if I can't install it on 18.04 I have to downgrade to 16.04.

Thanks by advance guys ! :) And sorry for my poor English, I'm French.

EDIT : I read this : [Openshot Video Editor 1.4.3-1.2 - How to stop it auto updating to v 2.43 etc in 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120996/openshot-video-editor-1-4-3-1-2-how-to-stop-it-auto-updating-to-v-2-43-etc-in?rq=1) but the person who sent the question didn't explained how he installed OpenShot and the dependances.

Answer (score 0):

You can install whatever version you want by **going to the repo** you want and finding the **needed .deb file**.

For example for the [OpenShot](https://launchpad.net/openshot/+download) 1.4.3 you can download it from [here](https://launchpad.net/openshot/1.4/1.4.3/+download/openshot_1.4.3-1_all.deb)

A quick way to install it:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/openshot/1.4/1.4.3/+download/openshot_1.4.3-1_all.deb -O openshot.deb
sudo dpkg -i openshot.deb
```

After that, if you have any **missing dependencies** run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To install all the needed ones

Comment: Hi, thanks for help !

I ran commands you gave me and locked openshot package as explained in my former edit. But, when I run the "-f install" line, it says this : (I put it in an answer because it's too long)

Comment: No problem, if my answer did help you please not forget to mark it ;)

Comment: I marked it, please read my former comment

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to install a package older of the one that is supported on Ubuntu 18.04 so it can't find the needed dependencies. Either you should find the supported distro and add it in the sources.list or you should go and download one by one the packages needed.

Comment: How can I know the right dependancy ? And where can I find them ? Sorry, I'm a new Ubuntu user so I'm such a noob

Comment: The needed dependencies are the ones on your comment: python-httplib2, python-imaging... Those are needed if you want to run the older version. You can find them on Launchpad but also just by typing <name> deb on Google.

Comment: If you are a newbie I would suggest to stick with this one download an older available one from their GitHub page https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/releases

Comment: I've find everything on pkgs.org, except the python-mlt5/3/2 one(if you have a link for that one). Before doing dpkg command, I want to have your opinion, do I have to choose : Sid, Jessie, Stretch or Buster ".deb" on pkgs.org ?

Comment: Dependancies have dependancies and some of them have dependancies, so it'll be very hard for me to do it manually. Is there a way for getting them with a command line ?

Comment: Yeah that's the problem when you are installing too old packages. I would suggest to just sticking with some newer ones like 2.1 if you don't want the latest one

Answer (score 0):

when I run :
sudo apt-get -f install
It give back :
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Correction des dépendances... a échoué.
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 openshot : Dépend: melt mais il n'est pas installé
            Dépend: python-httplib2 mais il n'est pas installé
            Dépend: python-imaging mais il n'est pas installable
            Dépend: python-mlt5 mais il n'est pas installable ou
                     python-mlt3 mais il n'est pas installable ou
                     python-mlt2 mais il n'est pas installable
            Dépend: python-pygoocanvas mais il n'est pas installable
            Dépend: python-xdg mais il n'est pas installé
            Dépend: python-support (>= 0.90.0) mais il n'est pas installable
            Recommande: openshot-doc mais il n'est pas installé
E: Erreur, pkgProblem::Resolve a généré des ruptures, ce qui a pu être causé par les paquets devant être gardés en l'état.
E: Impossible de corriger les dépendances

You can use google translate or reverso to see what it means, because I don't want to give you a broken translation.